# need to retrieve data from a different table that includes the text of the current table column in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a sysid and a status column in table 1, and I need to search for and retrieve data from table 2's sysid column that includes the text from table 1's sysid column.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSwz5.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrD0i.png)

Expecting output like below[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmq7q.png)

Comment: add your content in text/table format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Split sysid in Table1
2. Duplicate Table1
3. In Table1 rename sysid.1 to sysid and remove sysid.2
4. Duplicate rename sysid.2 to sysid, remove empty and remove sysid.1
5. Append Duplicate to Table1
6. Merge Table1 and Table2 on sysid

[image]